# Node.js What is the alternative solution to QueryString module

Tags: node.js, node-modules, query-string

Query string has a `leagcy` tag inside the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) site.

1. Should I no longer use this module?
2. Will it be removed in future versions?
3. What is the alternative solution to this module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I no longer use this module?

Yes.

In documentation:

> The querystring API is considered Legacy. While it is still
> maintained, new code should use the  API instead.